# What difference will it make if I add a Content.Header.Expires with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

I have seen the following:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
return response;
```

Can someone tell me what difference it will make if I add the Content.Header.Expires? Will this mean it will be cached on the client or on the server or ?  What if I do not add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This informs anything consuming your method that the response is valid for the next 300 seconds.

What the client and any caching proxies do with that information depends entirely on their specific configurations, but they may choose to use the cached response rather than re-requesting it.

If you don't add it, then your responses won't contain any caching information, so you'll (almost certainly) find that every time the client requests the data, your web service will receive the request, rather than it being satisfied by a cache.